# Adding Area atribute to the Html.ActionLink Does NOT Work

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, html.actionlink

First of all I would like to make a comment about .NET Core.. Having working with .NET Framework... .NET Core is a JOKE! I cannot believe that Microsoft has put out a platform that seems to be difficult to work with. Every step is a struggle to get something done that is effortless to do in .NET Framework. Now I am stuck on generating a simple anchor tag using  the Html.ActionLink (and other methods).. It seems that the Area attribute of the helper does not work. I can browser to the page I want to link to but ASP.NET using Razor cannot build the link for me. So now i am stuck with a huge project because I cannot add the area to the url. This is simply unproductive and a waste of time learning Core. Unfortunately I am too far into the project to go back to .NET Framework.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I am a successful 30 year programmer and have learned many technologies on my own and I have never experienced anything like this before! I was advised by seasoned programmers to stay away from Core... Now I know what they were talking about.

This is my code to create the link:

```
@Html.ActionLink("View", "Customer", "Accounts", new { CustomerID = Model.Customers[iRow].CustomerGUID }, new { @area = "Admin", @style = "", @class = "copy-01a" })
```

Comment: "First of all I would like to make a comment about .NET Core" - please don't. This isn't a site for commentary, it's a site for questions and answers. It would have been really helpful if you'd provided a [mcve] instead of ranting. (You've provided some code, but not told us anything about your site URL scheme, or what happens with the code you've given...)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add `@area` into routeValues :

```
@Html.ActionLink("View", "Customer", "Accounts", new { CustomerID = Model.Customers[iRow].CustomerGUID, @area = "Admin" }, new {  @style = "", @class = "copy-01a" })
```

or

```
@Html.ActionLink("View", "Customer", "Accounts", new { CustomerID = Model.Customers[iRow].CustomerGUID, area = "Admin" }, new {  @style = "", @class = "copy-01a" })
```

I do a demo it works fine.

[image]

You can read [Areas in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to know more.